# SSH problem towards my Pi

Tags: ssh

I am struggling  to get remotely connected to my Pi.

My set-up is the following:
ISP Broadband Modem -> TP Link WIFI router -> Pi
TP Link is set with Port-forward to  on port 22

I use the terminal on my Mac and do the following commands:

```
ping <LAN IP on TP Link>  #OK 
ping <MyPublicIP>         #OK 
ssh pi@<MyPublicIP>       #NotOK and timeout 
ssh pi@<MyInternalIPonPi> #OK
```

I run the following command:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo netstat -tlpn
tcp 0       0 0.0.0.0:22       0.0.0.0:* LISTEN      541/sshd        
tcp 6       0      0 :::22     :::*      LISTEN      541/sshd
```

What is missing?

Comment: Sounds like the Tp-Link port forwarding is not setup right or doesn't support it using coming from the the local IP or using the Wifi. I do the same thing with my fritz!box. Using the public IP to connecting to my ssh server this works.

Comment: From [TP-Link FAQ](http://www.tp-link.com/lk/faq-785.html) "If step 1 and 2 confirmed no problem, but you still fails to access the server remotely. Please check the WAN IP address on the status page of the router, and verify it’s a public IP address. If it is a privateIP address, which means there is an extra router/NAT in front of the TP-Link router, and you have to open the same port as your server’s for TP-Link router on that router/NAT.
( Note: private IP range:10.0.0.0—10.255.255.255； 172.16.0.0—172.31.255.255； 192.168.0.0—192.168.255.255)" Does that help?

Comment: This is **OBVIOUSLY** not a duplicate, as the OP has `ssh` working on his network. It is **off topic** as it is a problem with his router/modem.

Comment: Agreed.  If ssh is running and the pi can be pinged, *unless you've set up a firewall on the pi* (there is not one with Raspbian or most other distros by default), then the problem is not the pi, the problem is routing to the pi.

Comment: @Milliways Sorry, I guess I was so busy fixing the formatting that I failed to read the question carefully.